# In Carrierwave and Fog how to catch failed uploads and log them?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave, fog

When uploading a file using carrierwave errors can occur. For example, if there's an error while using Fog to upload to S3, we won't get an error message. Simply the file won't exist. So, how can I catch these errors with Carrierwave and Fog and log them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried [validating the integrity or processing of the fail image](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/wiki/How-to%3A-Validate-uploads-with-Active-Record)?

Also take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/20195812/1380867 post. I think this is the same problem